# Spark: How can DataFrame be Dataset[Row] if DataFrame's have a schema

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

[This article](https://databricks.com/blog/2016/07/14/a-tale-of-three-apache-spark-apis-rdds-dataframes-and-datasets.html) claims that a `DataFrame` in Spark is equivalent to a `Dataset[Row]`, but [this blog post](http://blog.madhukaraphatak.com/introduction-to-spark-two-part-3/) shows that a `DataFrame` has a schema.

Take the example in the blog post of converting an RDD to a `DataFrame`: if `DataFrame` were the same thing as `Dataset[Row]`, then converting an `RDD` to a `DataFrame`should be as simple

```scala
val rddToDF = rdd.map(value => Row(value))
```

But instead it shows that it's this

```scala
val rddStringToRowRDD = rdd.map(value => Row(value))
val dfschema = StructType(Array(StructField("value",StringType)))
val rddToDF = sparkSession.createDataFrame(rddStringToRowRDD,dfschema)
val rDDToDataSet = rddToDF.as[String]
```

Clearly a dataframe is actually a dataset of rows *and a schema*.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Spark 2.0, in code there is:
`type DataFrame = Dataset[Row]`

It is `Dataset[Row]`, just because of definition.

`Dataset` has also schema, you can print it using `printSchema()` function. Normally Spark infers schema, so you don't have to write it by yourself - however it's still there ;)

You can also do `createTempView(name)` and use it in SQL queries, just like DataFrames.

In other words, `Dataset` **=** `DataFrame from Spark 1.5` **+** `encoder`, that converts rows to your classes. After merging types in Spark 2.0, DataFrame becomes just an alias for `Dataset[Row]`, so without specified encoder.

About conversions: rdd.map() also returns `RDD`, it never returns DataFrame. You can do:

```
// Dataset[Row]=DataFrame, without encoder
val rddToDF = sparkSession.createDataFrame(rdd)
// And now it has information, that encoder for String should be used - so it becomes Dataset[String]
val rDDToDataSet = rddToDF.as[String]

// however, it can be shortened to:
val dataset = sparkSession.createDataset(rdd)
```

Answer (score 2):

Note (in addition to the answer of [T Gaweda](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5811800/t-gaw%c4%99da)) that there is a schema associated to each `Row` (`Row.schema`). However, this schema is not set until it is integrated in a `DataFrame` (or `Dataset[Row]`)

```
scala> Row(1).schema
res12: org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType = null

scala> val rdd = sc.parallelize(List(Row(1)))
rdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = ParallelCollectionRDD[5] at parallelize at <console>:28
scala> spark.createDataFrame(rdd,schema).first
res15: org.apache.spark.sql.Row = [1]
scala> spark.createDataFrame(rdd,schema).first.schema
res16: org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType = StructType(StructField(a,IntegerType,true))
```